# Get first alphanumeric or special character in string from start index

Tags: c#, string

Say I have a string such as:
`ma, 100` or, `ma, word`, or even `ma.   , *+` etc.

How can I find the position of the first character that is not some form of punctuation (i.e full stop, comma, colon, semi-colon) or whitespace, after an index. So, in the last example above, I'd want to get the position of `*` when I pass in 1 as a start index (zero-based).

Comment: regex /[^.,;:]/ and substring

Comment: @LoganMurphy I'm new to C#. How would I apply that regex and get the position of the first match?

Comment: @Downvoter why the downvote? What is wrong with this question? I don't understand why there have been votes to close this, especially seeing as though there are no comments

Comment: Maybe regex is too complicated then. Just iterate through the string and see if the current character is an invalid symbol or not.

Comment: One of the votes to close indicated you hadn't posted any code attempts, which implies that you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @AustinSalonen I didn't think I needed to in cases like this to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method like this

```
public static int GetFirstNonPunctuationCharIndex(string input, int startIndex, char[] punctuation)
{
    //Move the startIndex forward one because we ignore the index user set
    startIndex = startIndex + 1 < input.Length ? startIndex + 1 : input.Length;                 

    for (int i = startIndex  ; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!punctuation.Contains(input[i]) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i]))
        {
             return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

You would call it by passing in the string, starting index, and an array of characters you consider to be punctuation.

```
string myString = @"ma. , *+";
char[] puncArray = new char[4] { '.', ',', ';', ':' };
int index = GetFirstNonPunctuationCharIndex(myString, 1, puncArray)
```

Normally I'd use the [Char.IsPunctuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3ahtyy.aspx) method but apparently it considers `*` to be a punctuation character so you'll have to roll your own like above.

Answer (score 4):

Create an array of the characters that you want to match and call [String.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56y4ddbk.aspx)

For example:

```
const string GoodCharsStr =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy";
readonly char[] GoodChars = GoodCharsStr.ToCharArray();

string search = "ma, 100";
int position = search.IndexOfAny(GoodChars, 1);
if (position == -1)
{
    // not found
}
char foundChar = search[position];
```

Comment: Hmmm... thanks for the answer! What's the difference between this and the other methods? Particularly performance wise.

Comment: @Andy: It looks like the other answers do essentially the same thing. I don't know how `IndexOfAny` is implemented. Perhaps you should test it along with the other solutions to determine which is faster.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will do some research, but for this purpose I can see that I'd be better with one of the other methods because then I can check for disallowed characters (of which there are fewer - thus less iterations).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to define what exactly a special character is.

If it's a non-consecutive set (according to ASCII ordering, see http://www.asciitable.com/) then you'll need to define a new allowed character set and check against that set.

Something like this should work:

```
public const string allowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.,";

public int RetrieveIndex(string input, int startIndex)
{
    for (var x = startIndex; x < input.length; x++)
    {
        if (allowed.IndexOf(input[x])==-1)
        {
            return x;
        }
     }

    return -1;
}
```

However, if it is a consecutive set as defined by the ASCII standard:

Just figure out which range is considered acceptable or special and check against that by converting the character to an integer and checking if it lies within the range. This would prove faster than the calls to `allowed.IndexOf(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The link you provided doesn't work for me, but by special characters I mean like `*+_/$`, but your method will work perfectly. Just didn't know if there was a more efficient way, with less lines of code.

Comment: RegEx would indeed be faster. So would the ASCII subset. Looks like their website is down atm. But just look up ASCII tables in general, and you may see how they could help.

Comment: I don't really want to be limited to ASCII though as one day I intend to widen the scope of my program. Could you give an example of RegEx?

Comment: ASCII is a standard and thus is not really limiting. Either way, you'll need to make a decision as whether to check against a list of allowed characters, or check a list of disallowed (special) characters. Whichever is shorter would be the best for efficiency. As for regex, it's a highly optimized methodology of string comparison operations for checking specific patterns and the like. It's a fairly big field - and you'll find there are a hundred different ways to do the same thing. So, I'm afraid just giving you a bit of code may not help much. I suggest you read up on it and use a online tool

Comment: Fair enough. Well I do know a bit about RegEx but I will look into it more, and I will be checking for disallowed characters seeing as though that list is shorter.